# Is it possible to use prepared statements for dual in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

For example, if i have declared

```
String SQL = "select ? from dual";
```

Create a prepared statement for the above query

```
PreparedStatement preStmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

And then try to add the expression as

```
preStmt.setString(1, expression);
```

How would that work? Is it possible to use it that way?

Comment: I haven’t tried it myself. I see no reason why we shouldn’t expect it to work. Did *you* try?

Comment: No, those `?` are used for _values_, not for identifiers. Let's say `dual`, whatever that might be, has a column named 'foo' as well as a column named 'bar' - then you can't use this to make one preparedstatement that alternatives returns the value of either column.

Comment: Note that e.g. `SELECT 'hello' FROM foo` is legal SQL and just returns literally the string 'hello' once for every entry in `foo`. So, legal, but useless. That's what will happen if you try this.

Comment: [Oracle's `dual` table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Selecting-from-the-DUAL-Table.html) is a single row with a column called `dummy` (with value `'X'`). Selecting a literal value from it is common for generating CTEs, and it's somewhat optimised for this. So yes, this would work; but the result set would be a single row with the value you provided, which seems a bit pointless. What are you really trying to do/achieve?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Given that the OP’s understanding of `dual` agrees with that of Alex Poole (which agrees with mine except I don’t know what CTE stands for), we can safely take it that the OP is trying to get the same value back that they supply, not trying to alter between columns (since there is only one column).

Comment: CTE is common table expression - a.k.a subquery factoring. What isn't really clear is what `expression` actually is in the `setString()` call. If that is a string like "3" then this will work but just return 3 or "3" depending on the `rset.get*()` call, which isn't helpful. If it's a string like "3+4" that you want Oracle to evaluate as an expression then it will fail; with `getInt()` it will error, with `getString()` it will just return the same string again (I think). If it's a Java expression which evaluates to a number/string/whatever then you wouldn't need to involve the database...

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks. You are obviously correct. If the expression is `"Stand with Ukraine"`, then that string is returned. If it is `"" + 3 + 4`, then the string `"34"` is returned. Oracle can do noting but return the string as it receives it. Whether that’s useful? Usually not, but I’m not the one to rule out that it may be in special situations.